# Is there a way to avoid making calls to context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, defValue) when editing multiple preferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

In my android app I have

```
    SharedPreferences usernamePref = context.getSharedPreferences(USERNAME_PREF, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String username = usernamePref.getString(USERNAME_PREF, ERROR);

    SharedPreferences emailPref = context.getSharedPreferences(EMAIL_PREF, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String email = emailPref.getString(EMAIL_PREF, ERROR);

    SharedPreferences passwordPref = context.getSharedPreferences(PASSWORD_PREF, context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String password = usernamePref.getString(PASSWORD_PREF, ERROR);
```

The reason this is confusing me is because the key is being used twice, which seems redundant. So I am wondering, is it possible to just get all the preferences from a single `SharedPreferences` object?

Comment: Heads up you are using `password = usernamePref.getString` when I think you mean to use `passwordPref` instead. This might become moot if you use a single `SharedPreferences` anyways though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way I typically do it:

```
PreferenceManger prefManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String username = prefManager.getString(USERNAME_PREF);
String email = prefManager.getString(EMAIL_PREF);
String password = prefManager.getString(PASSWORD_PREF);
```

**Note:**  You will want to be editting the single SharedPreferences for your app, not individual as you have it now.  To edit it this way do the following:

```
PreferenceManger prefManager = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefManager.edit();
editor.putString(USERNAME_PREF, usernameString);
editor.putString(EMAIL_PREF, emailString);
editor.putString(PASSWORD_PREF, passwordString);
editor.commit();
```

Comment: That's the cleaner code I was looking for, I think I will try using this.

Answer (score 0):

How are you storing the preferences? It would make sense to use a single `SharedPreferences`.

Just use the editor on for one `SharedPreferences` and use `putString` with your different keys.

Comment: I was storing them one by one like that also, So could I make a key `MAIN_PREFERENCES` that I use to get a single `SharedPreferences` object and then store multiple key/value pairs in that shared preference?